# How can I optimize my web server to run MyBB faster?

Tags: mysql, apache-2.4, php5

I am running a web server with MyBB and Pingdom says it takes 629ms to load my site's index. I was wondering if there is a way to lower this. This is the information I have about page generation time:

```
MyBB Debug Information

Page Generation

Page Generation Statistics
Page Generation Time:   55 ms   No. DB Queries: 16
PHP Processing Time:    53 ms (96.13%)  DB Processing Time: 2 ms (3.87%)
Extensions Used:    mysqli, xml Global.php Processing Time: 47 ms
PHP Version:    5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19   Server Load:    0
GZip Encoding Status:   Disabled    No. Templates Used: 78 (75 Cached / 3 Manually Loaded)
Memory Usage:   2.5 MB (2621440 bytes)  Memory Limit:   128M
```

To provide further debugging information I am providing this link to Pingdom's site speed test to provider further information about the page: https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/bSkZOI/https://sinful.pw/

I am trying to optimize the site to run as fast as possible. I am running the apache2 web server and would like to know what steps I can take to optimize it's load time as much as possible. I also have CloudFlare in front of the site since they cache certain files. PHP5 is configured to utilize the opcode caching.

**EDIT:** This is not a duplicate question. I asked how to optimize my web server not how to do load testing. Can someone please explain how they are remotely similar?

Comment: @Colt no it's not a duplicate at all. This has nothing to do with load testing. This has to do with asking how to optimize software for a specific use case.

Comment: There is more than half a second discrepancy between the numbers you posted from "MyBB Debug Information" and Pingdom. Start by looking into what that discrepancy is. You also need to disable or bypass CloudFlare while working on things like this, as it will interfere with your attempts to narrow down any such problems.

Comment: I cannot disable CloudFlare as the moment I do 1000 attack bots start attacking the site again.

Comment: Then you need to deploy a separate development environment where you can test it without Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

The semi-automatic way to increase website speed, which requires almost no in-depth knowledge of your system's internal workings is installing mod_pagespeed on your apache. Please follow this guide to do it:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/download